# Javascript arguments object parameter parsing

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

i'm issuing a problem in understanding how function's arguments object parses.

The code i'm analysing:

```
function foo(something) {
    console.log(something); // outputs 3
    return this.a + something;
}

function bind(fn, obj) {
    return function () {
      return fn.apply(obj, arguments);
    };
}

var obj = {
   a: 2
};

var bar = bind(foo, obj);
var b = bar(3, 5, 6);
```

The function foo console logs its argument named "something", which should be arguments object. Why i'm getting just the first param passed and other params are ignored? I thought i should get the whole arguments object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With .apply() you pass all parameters as array. This means, if you have a function with two parameters like:

```
functionWithTwo(a,b) {}
```

you can pass the parameters with an array with two value:

```
[1,3]
```

If you now pass an array with more than 2 fields, the others are ignored, because your target function just accepts 2 arguments.

This is excactly what happens in your example. You pass an array [3, 5, 6] to a function that only acceps 1 parameter (something). So only the first value, 3, is present.

Comment: I'm passing an array (by the way, type of arguments parameter is object) [3, 5, 6] and getting the first its first element. Why so?

For me now it looks that i have function, which outputs its arguments wrong. For example:

    `function test(arg){
      console.log(arg);    
    }

    test([1,2,3]) // outputs [1,2,3]`
   
but i'm getting something like this:
   `test([1,2,3]) // [1]`

Comment: Image that .apply() maps an given array to a functions arguments. It loops over all elements of the given array, so to say, and maps every match. You just have a match for arguments[0], because foo has only one parameter